# Dynamically assigning values to a jQuery array from database using ASP.NET Core razor pages

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a autocomplete functionality, which is hardcoded currently. Please find the code below.

```javascript
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var availableTags = [
            "superadmin",
            "admin",
            "user1",
            "user2"
        ];
        function split(val) {
            return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }
        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }

        $("#RequestorBox")
            // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
            .on("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
            .autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                        availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
                },
                focus: function () {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var terms = split(this.value);
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push(ui.item.value);
                    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push("");
                    this.value = terms.join(", ");
                    return false;
                }
            });
            });
```

```html
<label class="control-label" for="tags">Requestor/Country User</label>
<input id="RequestorBox" size="50">
```

Currently the ***var availabletags*** array is hardcoded, I want to populate those values from database using ASP.NET C#(Razor Pages).

How can I call the ASP.NET method here and assign the value to jQuery array. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thats really too a big a question for one question. There are loads of resources available to assist with this sort of thing but this site is for specific technical problems, not complete project solutions.

Comment: You have two options: 1) include the array in your Model and output as a js array (so the js continues to see it as hardcoded by the time it gets to the client)  2) make an ajax call to load the data then setup your RequestorBox in the ajax callback (`.done` / `success:`).  The easiest option is to include it in your Model